# I'm using karate.callSingle for calling Authorization. It gets expired after 2 hours. Can we configure callSingle to call after 2 hours?

Tags: karate, karate-call-single

If I can regenerate Authorization again after some time (say 2hours), I can use it. Else I need to add a scheduler to call Authorization after 2 hours.

This is the below code that I have used to call Authorization in karate-config.js and I have used this throughout the project.

```
var websecAPI = karate.callSingle('classpath:service/Regression/RestClient.feature@restclient',config);
config.Authorization = websecAPI.Authorization;
```

Comment: you can write some custom logic to do this, see linked thread

Comment: if you are saying your test suite will be running for that long and you need to regenerate the token mid test run after some time period(token expiration),  check out [configure callSingleCache](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#configure-callsinglecache) 

this will automatically reinvoke the callSingle after a given time period. I use this in long running karate-gatling performance tests and it works well for automatically re-creating the auth token when it expires.